# К трактовке можно обращаться?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Интересно, что во Пскове, в нашем Спасо-Преображенском Мирожском
>   монастыре, росписи которого создавались в первой
>   половине XII века, греческие художники обращаются к той же
>   самой трактовке!

Comment: Это была их собственная трактовка (с чьей-то в видении критика совпавшая) или уже известная и сознательно воспроизведённая? К своей, конечно же, нельзя "обращаться".

Comment: Из чего делаю вывод, что автор должен уточниться и проясниться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попытаться задать поиск в гугло-книгах по запросу ["обращается к трактовке"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1047&bih=465&tbm=bks&ei=IuYeXYDQLaitrgTgs6_gAQ&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5%22&oq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22960.24226.0.24826.2.2.0.0.0.0.129.246.0j2.2.0....0...1c.2.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Gs0eL5uJiHY). Для большего количества примеров можно немного видоизменять запрос, используя другие словоформы слов в нём. Может быть, у кого-то и возникнут сомнения в авторитетности и добротности всех этих источников, но только не у меня.

Comment: Гризлик, первая же ссылка (по твоей ссылке) ну крутая: ***интерпретация обращается к трактовке***... Спасибо. Но в удалённом ответе Niemand'а говорится: так жить нельзя. Мне и мотивации никакой не надо: сунусь к автору с "нельзя".

Answer (score 0):

К трактовке вполне можно обращаться, если это позволено по контексту.
Есть "нечто" - у это "нечта" есть разные трактовки. 
Роман ***"12 Стульев"***. Две экранизации суть две трактовки.
А что там у вас - не понятно.

Если под трактовкой имеется в виду сама живопись того самого века, то я сильно сомневаюсь в корректности подобного.